# Density function plot not really vertical - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I am plotting a density function with the `ggplot2` package. I noticed that the first and second vertical line are not perfectly rectangular, although as far as I understand they should be, or? I also found this to be the case, when plotting a distribution of the binomial distribution that the the steps are not really rectangular.

```
library(ggplot2)
p_uniform_density <- ggplot(data.frame(x = c(-2, 17.5)), aes(x)) + 
stat_function(fun = dunif, args = list(min = 0, max = 15), size=1.2 ) +
theme_bw() +
labs(y = "f(X)", x = "X") +
theme(text = element_text(size=20) ,  panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.2, linetype = 'solid', colour = "grey"), 
    panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', colour = "grey")) +
scale_x_continuous( breaks = c(-2:17.5))
```

[image: Density plot with skewed start and end values]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `n=1e3` in `stat_function`

Comment: alternatively, `geom="step"` would always be straight, but might be slightly offset

Comment: I used `n=1e3` since adding the option `geom="step"` offset the function quite a bit, which was not really better, than before. 
Thanks a lot.